# github angularJS bootstrap tutorial not working for me

Tags: angularjs

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Above is the link for the best tutorial and code i've found for angularJS bootstrap combined elements.

Code for html and angularJS is given for :datepicker,timepicker,typeheads,accordion,lot more...best site to refer.

Now my only problem is that when i tried accordion from that page from where i directly copy pasted the angularJS and html code, it did not seem to work. I tried the typehead and the accordion.

Do I need to download , save and link a some file locally?
i dont seem to get it! anyone who has tried the above can just tell me?

typehead.html:

```
                <head>

      <title>Angular Accordion</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
      <script src="typehead.js"></script>





    </head>

    <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
        <a>
          <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
          <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        </a>
      </script>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
        <div class="custom-popup-wrapper" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
          <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
            <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
              <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </script>


      <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

        <h4>Static arrays</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
        </div>

        <h4>ngModelOptions support</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{ngModelOptionsSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ngModelOptionsSelected" ng-model-options="modelOptions" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true"
        typeahead-min-length="0">

        <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </body>
```

typehead.js:

```
                 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

     angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

       var _selected;


       $scope.selected = undefined;
       $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
       // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
       $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
         return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
           params: {
             address: val,
             sensor: false
           }
         }).then(function(response) {
           return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
             return item.formatted_address;
           });
         });
       };

       $scope.ngModelOptionsSelected = function(value) {
         if (arguments.length) {
           _selected = value;
         } else {
           return _selected;
         }
       };

       $scope.modelOptions = {
         debounce: {
           default: 500,
           blur: 250
         },
         getterSetter: true
       };

       $scope.statesWithFlags = [{
         'name': 'Alabama',
         'flag': '5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Alaska',
         'flag': 'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Arizona',
         'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Arkansas',
         'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'California',
         'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Colorado',
         'flag': '4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Connecticut',
         'flag': '9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Delaware',
         'flag': 'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Florida',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Georgia',
         'flag': '5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Hawaii',
         'flag': 'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Idaho',
         'flag': 'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Illinois',
         'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Indiana',
         'flag': 'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Iowa',
         'flag': 'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Kansas',
         'flag': 'd/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Kentucky',
         'flag': '8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Louisiana',
         'flag': 'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Maine',
         'flag': '3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Maryland',
         'flag': 'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Massachusetts',
         'flag': 'f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Michigan',
         'flag': 'b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Minnesota',
         'flag': 'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Mississippi',
         'flag': '4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Missouri',
         'flag': '5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Montana',
         'flag': 'c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Nebraska',
         'flag': '4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Nevada',
         'flag': 'f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Hampshire',
         'flag': '2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Jersey',
         'flag': '9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Mexico',
         'flag': 'c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New York',
         'flag': '1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'North Carolina',
         'flag': 'b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'North Dakota',
         'flag': 'e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Ohio',
         'flag': '4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Oklahoma',
         'flag': '6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Oregon',
         'flag': 'b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Pennsylvania',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Rhode Island',
         'flag': 'f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'South Carolina',
         'flag': '6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'South Dakota',
         'flag': '1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Tennessee',
         'flag': '9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Texas',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Utah',
         'flag': 'f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Vermont',
         'flag': '4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Virginia',
         'flag': '4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Washington',
         'flag': '5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'West Virginia',
         'flag': '2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Wisconsin',
         'flag': '2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Wyoming',
         'flag': 'b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png'
       }];
     });
```

above is the exact code i copy pasted from the documentation but failed to get the result!

Following was the error shown by the console:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            (index):1
```

Console error 2 after adding correct links from user response 'shankar Gurav':

```
        Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:68:12
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:2015:17
            at ensure (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1939:38)
            at module (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:2013:14)
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4503:22
            at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:321:20)
            at loadModules (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4487:5)
            at createInjector (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4409:19)
            at doBootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1691:20)
            at bootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1712:12)
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo&p….googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.js%3A1712%3A12)
```

Comment: your code is missing ng-app directive.

Answer (score 0):

It does works when you add references to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Check the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2I3xVdgRBQCXzbB0ryOa?p=preview) with your code.

Comment: how does the same code you have on plunker not work on my xampp local server :-/ i tried evrythng!!!! links all correct!   the new error in the console log is posted in the question named 'console error2'

Comment: added ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" to <body> tag! still the same error in console!

Comment: error points that somewhere your module is not able to instantiate, either dependencies are not being provisioned or there is problem in your controllers (this shouldn't be the case as I copied and worked for me). I don't have xampp server installed to analysis.

Answer (score 0):

After the end of your `<script>` tag, add a body tag with ng-app directive.

```
 <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo"> 
   <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

        <h4>Static arrays</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
        </div>

        <h4>ngModelOptions support</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{ngModelOptionsSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ngModelOptionsSelected" ng-model-options="modelOptions" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0">

        <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </body>
```